# Chromecast automatically suspends session in iOS intermittently?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

In our application after casting the video for sometime, the casting gets suspended intermittently.

-(void)sessionManager:(GCKSessionManager *)sessionManager didSuspendSession:(GCKSession *)session withReason:(GCKConnectionSuspendReason)reason

gets fired automatically. "GCKConnectionSuspendReasonNetworkError" is the reason we are receiving

Answer (score 0):

That simply means there was a network connectivity issue; the framework would try for a few seconds to reconnect and recover (that suspension message is more like a heads-up); if it fails, you'd see a disconnect event.

Comment: Is there is a chance that it may be caused by some other means? Because at the same time we tried casting in other apps like youtube etc and it was working fine .

Comment: The "reason" that the callback is providing (GCKConnectionSuspendReasonNetworkError) , based on your post, points to network issue.

Comment: We enabled the logs and we can see that the message "[GCKCastSocket readMessages] : message too large: 1681209701 (64353965)" is getting logged before connection gets closed. "[GCKCastDeviceConnector castSocket:didReceiveMessage:] : Invalid message data:" message also gets logged

Comment: What is the nature of message that is too large? Are you sending large data  or a queue with too many items?

Comment: The Xcode logs can be viewed from the following link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zec4ajud2ajncl7/error_log_cc_suspend_disconnect_resume_issue.rtf?dl=0

We are passing only 10 items to the queue. We are not inserting items into existing query we are replacing the current item with the new one.

Comment: The issue seems to be the size of message exceeding the maximum size allowed. You need to investigate what you are doing on your receiver side that is causing the size to get too large.

Comment: We checked our receiver implementation and couldn't find any issues. We were able to reproduce the same issue with GoogleCast sample application provided by Google. Xcode logs of the same is https://www.dropbox.com/s/tzfg2q746ib1tpl/castvideos-ios_queue_error_log.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Did you use your own receiver or Reference Receiver/Styled or Default? If you used your own custom receiver and reproduced that, then please use the reference receiver or a styled/default receiver since I suspect, your receiver might be at fault.

Comment: We were able to reproduce this using the sample receiver and sender provided by Google. The receiverId of the sample application provided by Google is 4F8B3483.This issue occurred when we added some items to the ChromeCast playlist queue. This issue occurs only in iOS device.

Comment: In our application we are adding around 10 items to the playlist. In the sample provided by Google we got this issue after adding around 8-9 items

Comment: That doesn't seem like too many items. Please open a ticket on our issue tracker at https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list so we can look at the issue and address that, thanks.

Comment: Issue raised on Google https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=1077&thanks=1077&ts=1484114149

Comment: Sometime session get suspend even when individual item is playing and when I try to stop casting application crashes with message "Session is not active"
Can you please update on same ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar google-cast-sdk issue is reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=1036&start=100)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the GoogleCast Framework. Google accepted it and released a patch. Upgrade your framework to 3.5.3 and the problem should be solved.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes
https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/GoogleCastSDK-Public-3.5.3-Release-ios.zip